# How Do SaaS Companies Deal With Corporate Clients That Have Restrictive Firewalls

Tags: security, architecture, firewall, saas

I'm responsible for a web application that is used in several corporate environments. The application is also used by many non-corporate users. Recently I've been hearing issues with corporate users not being able to user certain features of the application. I'm guessing (don't know for sure) that they are behind firewalls that are extremely restrictive and may be blocking certain external resources (javascript files, etc).

I'm not a network security expert or system administrator, so my knowledge of how corporate IT sets up their firewalls is pretty limited. I would guess that they would need to whitelist the various urls used by the application?

Are there other approaches?

Just wondering if anyone else has been in this position and how you dealt with it ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in company I've worked we had very similar problem. The solution was really easy, if the firewall was the true problem, client had to add an exception to firewalls rules for the application.